# Prove that there is an natural number consisting of digits 0 and 7 which is divisible by $359$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

How can I approach this kind of question ? I thought about Euler's totient function and gcd but i dont know if they are related to this question

Comment: We do not even need the digit $0$

Comment: $359$ is prime, how can you divide it ? I think, we should divide the number by $359$ instead.

Comment: Hint : $$10^{358}\equiv 1\mod 359$$ because of Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: @zwim yes thats what i mean

Comment: If the given number is composite, but coprime to $10$, you need the more general Euler-theorem giving $$10^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1\mod n$$ If the given number is not coprime to $10$, we need also zeros to get a number as desired.

Comment: @Peter you point out the $7$-repunit as solution, if we assume at least one zero, the answer if different though.

Comment: Well, you can mutlitply with $10$ to get a zero. If you want a zero in another place, you can take the sevens , add a zero and then the same number of sevens again to get the desired number.

Comment: $7007070777=359 \cdot 19518303$ is the smallest one by the way

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Use the pigeonhole principle to argue that among the sequence $7,77,777,7777,\dots$, there exist (at least) two numbers that have the same remainder upon division by $359$.

Comment: $7\cdot \frac{10^k-1}{9}$ was brilliant

Answer (score 0):

Allowable numbers look like "$70077770777070777700$", i.e., a sum of $7*10^n$ for a handful of $n$. We could also write such a number as "$7\times10011110111010111100$". The numbers $359$ and $7$ are coprime, so $359$ will only divide $70077770777070777700$ if it divides $10011110111010111100$.

I'll assume you know a little modular arithmetic, which is quite useful for such problems. The short version is: because $10$ is coprime to $359$, the number $10$ generates the multiplicative group of integers modulo $359$. That means, in particular, that $10^m = 1$ for some $m$. So one solution is
\begin{equation}
7\sum_{i=1}^{359} 10^{mi} \equiv 7\sum_{i=1}^{359} 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{359}\,.
\end{equation}

Comment: In retrospect, Peter's comment to your question proves the existence of such $m$ a little more directly. :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Peter](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82961/peter) in comments, by Fermat's little theorem,

we have that $359$ divides $10^{358}-1=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{357}9\times10^n.$

Since $359$ and $9$ are relatively prime, this means $359$ divides $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{357}10^n$ and therefore $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{357}7\times10^n,$

which is a number whose digits are all $7$.

(If a $0$ digit is required, multiply it by $10$.

Also, it happens to be that $359$ divides $10^{179}-1$.)